# How to reduce the font size according to the length of the header in php?

Tags: php, html, css, size, string-length

I've created a form which displays header in the starting of the page.if the length of the header is larger it displays two lines and it looks bad, so please tell me is there any way to reduce the font size according to the length of the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First methode** : You can use `media-queries` :

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1204px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
```

**Second methode** : You can give it manually according to screen size of screen.Just have a look of different screen size and add manually the font size.

**Then,** You can use `em` or `%`. Also, CSS3 have some new values for sizing things relative to the current viewport size: `vw`, `vh`, and `vmin`. See [link](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) about that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use "em" (font-size: 1.1em) or percentage(font-size: 20%) in font-size. But I think you should share your screenshot to give more clear idea of problem